# how to put \neq in bookmark

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

The not equal sign (`$\neq$`)  becomes equal sign(=) in hyperref's bookmark. I know that `\texorpdfstring` will work for this, but I can not find `\textneq`, maybe another name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `\newcommand\textneq{\ensuremath{\neq}}` work? (i.e. put this in your preamble and then use `\textneq` in the bookmark?

Comment: This changes nothing.

Comment: Not all math symbols are available for text mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the actual ≠ symbol:

```
\texorpdfstring{$A\neq B$}{A ≠ B}
```

You need to load `hyperref` with the `[unicode]` option for this to work.

Your source file also needs to be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: pdflatex get mojibake, xelatex OK.

Comment: @Ma Ming: I don't understand your comment.  You don't need xelatex for this solution to work.  What does 'pdflatex get mojibake' mean?  Did the solution work for you?  If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: @Ma Ming: you need to make sure that the encoding of your input file is UTF-8 (it seems that 'mojibake'=unintelligible characters).

Comment: Thanks, I figued out it. xelatex uses unicode by default.

Answer (score 3):

`\texorpdfstring` is OK. `\neq` is ≠ (unicode 0x2260)