# Math symbol in section heading

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, best-practices

I have a section heading which includes an epsilon. Furthermore I am using the "hyperref" package to create links in my PDF document.

When compiling I get a strange warning that a math symbol is not allowed in a PDF string, e.g. `Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing \varepsilon on input line 6.`

However, if I open the compiled PDF there are no obvious errors and all links are clickable. Am I missing something, or can I just ignore this warning? Are there any alternatives to achieve the same result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$\varepsilon$SOA}

Text about $\varepsilon$SOA.

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the compiled example]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the pdf, the link itself (such as the one you see under Bookmarks in Adobe Reader) will not be able to display special characters. Check `\texorpdfstring{}{}` in hyperref manual.

Comment: Hi, `\section{\texorpdfstring{$\varepsilon$}{e}SOA}` is what you are looking for. It has been discussed here before, I'll try to find it.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53513/11002) [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8579/11002)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Option `pdfencoding=auto` or `unicode` enables bookmarks in Unicode with more symbols.
- Option `psdextra` defines lots of math symbols, however it misses `\varepsilon`.
- Then `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` can be used to define a bookmark replacement string for commands.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\varepsilon{\textepsilon}}
\usepackage{bookmark}% faster updated bookmarks

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$\varepsilon$SOA}

Text about $\varepsilon$SOA.

\end{document}
```

If the warnings about `math shift` should also be removed, then `\texorpdfstring` helps:

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{$\varepsilon$}{\textepsilon}SOA}
```

Comment: WHAT? I've been using \texorpdfstring{} this whole time when I could have used pdfencoding=auto? Dammit.

Comment: Thanks for the combination to remove LaTeX warnings, which I want to keep at 0 (to get the green (instead of red) line at the end of my compile script :-))