# How do you input maths into a section header?

Tags: sectioning, unicode-math, code

so I am currently in the process of making a summary for my maths subject. I'm a new TeX user and using pdfTeX on TeXworks.

I want to make this to show x=f(y) in the header as it would look like with maths typesetting in the body. What code will I need to use so that x=f(y) looks like it's maths, rather than normal paragraph text as a section header?

My code I already have is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
```

And after other stuff

```
\section{Summary of Rules and Formulas}

\section{Differentiation}

\subsection{Preliminary Knowledge}
\label{labelone}

\subsection{{\[x=f(y)\]}}
\label{labeltwo}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With `\[x=f(y)\]` you get *display* math; you can use `\(x=f(y)\)` for inline math.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251491/math-symbol-in-section-heading

Comment: Please be aware that with `hyperref` not any content in the heading of a structure command can go to the bookmarks, so you might need `\texorpdfstring{TeX Content}{Bookmark content}`, i.e. be careful what is written to the bookmarks